# Is the set $\{(x,y): x \in \mathbb{Q}, y \in \mathbb{R} \}$ closed?

Tags: real-analysis

Is the set $ X = \{(x,y): x \in \mathbb{Q}, y \in \mathbb{R} \}$ closed?

I think no, because if i choose a sequence $x_n \to \pi \not\in X$ then $(x_n,y)$ is in $X$ but it's limit point is not so $X$ is not closed. However, the complement of $X = \{(x,y): x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}, y \in \mathbb{R} \}$ is most certainly open - so this implies that $X$ is closed?

Where am i going wrong

Comment: Why do you think the complement is open?

Comment: I mean, we have that for the complement $x$ as all the irrational numbers, between any two irrational numbers there is another irrational number, and same goes for any real number so we can mostcertainly draw a ball in the set for some $r >0$

Comment: That is not true. Any ball with will contain a rational number so the ball will not be contained in the set of irrational numbers.

Comment: It is dense in the plane. What does that tell you about its closure?

Comment: You might try to consider the "original" definition of _closure_: a point $P$ is in the closure of a set if every open ball around $P$ intersects the set.

Comment: Closed in what? Sets are not closed, in and of themselves, they are closed relative to another set with a topology.

Comment: Presumably he means the usual topology on $\mathbb R^2$.